# How Facebook organize posts in news feed page

Tags: sql, facebook

I have always wondered how Facebook organize  posts in news feed page. Facebook doesn't use date and time to organize  posts in news feed page. This is obvious when some posts acquire many likes or comments. These posts, in spite they may be older posts, will be displayed first.

let's suppose a simple database table for posts :

```
Post_Id
Post_Owner_Id
Post_Text
Post_Image
Post_Date
```

So what field (or fields) that must be added to organize posts like the one in Facebook ?

Comment: Probably a table for comments and a table for likes.

Comment: Of Course there are table for likes, comments and share, but I ask how to organize posts. I we suppose (for example) that the post with many likes will show first, the same post will always show first.

Comment: I'm voting to close this as *too broad*. Unless somebody here works at Facebook and is willing to divulge what is probably one of their most closely guarded pieces of work, I don't think you're going to get a satisfactory answer.

Comment: I thinks there are a combination of fields to decide what post should display first (the number of likes, number of shares, number of comments  , date of post and some other fields). But how to use these fields to organize posts

Comment: Generally speaking (and I could be completely wrong), they would have some algorithms that build an index based on all the relevant factors. I highly doubt that what you're seeing in a news feed comes directly from database queries. I also have my doubts that Facebook even use a relational database

Answer (score 1):

The algorithm for how Facebook sorts the newsfeed isn't public from what I've heard, but what the algorithm looks for isn't completely.

Have a look at these articles for a slight idea on what they do and why.

[Bufferapp - Decoding the Facebook newsfeed](https://blog.bufferapp.com/facebook-news-feed-algorithm)

[Forbes - Facebook Changes News Feed Algorithm To Prioritize Content From Friends Over Pages](http://www.forbes.com/sites/amitchowdhry/2015/04/23/facebook-changes-news-feed-algorithm-to-prioritize-content-from-friends-over-pages/)

[Everything You Need To Know About Facebook’s News Feed Algorithm](http://singlegrain.com/facebooks-news-feed-algorithm/)

So if you are wanting to recreate their algorithm, you could get a *very* rough imitation by sorting based on date rounded to the closest week, second by the type of post it is (message, page, etc) then perhaps the number of likes it got.

Which means you would need number of likes and the Post_Type attributes.

You would also need to have it sort them based on friend status (direct or friends-of-friends) and whether or not the post comes from someone verified such as a celebrity.

There is so much to it.